# How to find a math solution for solving a task?

Tags: python, math, primes

I'm looking at solutions for an old coding competition and I'm wondering how they figured out this solution.

The problem is this: Count how many unique numbers in range of numStart - numEnd are dividable by at least one prime in a list of given primes.

First I thought "Sure, let's just make a for loop that goes through the range of numStart - numEnd and check if I can divide my iterator with at least one of the primes", that works but it was way too slow... and that's when I decided to check the answers.

My code:

```py
# numStart: Start from number
# numEnd: End on number
# numOfPrimes: How many primes will we be checking

numStart,numEnd,numOfPrimes = map(int, input().split())
primes = list(map(int, input().split()))

# Input can look like this:
# >21 180 4
# >7 3 13 2

counter = 0
for testNum in range(numStart, numEnd + 1):
    for prime in primes:
        if testNum % prime == 0:
            counter += 1
            break

print(counter)
# Output would look like this:
# >118
```

The solution:

```py
from itertools import combinations

# numStart: Start from number
# numEnd: End on number
# numOfPrimes: How many primes will we be checking

numStart,numEnd,numOfPrimes = map(int, input().split())
primes = list(map(int, input().split()))

# Input can look like this:
# >21 180 4
# >7 3 13 2

result = 0
for j in range(1,numOfPrimes+1):
    for c in combinations(primes, j):
        num = 1
        for x in c: num *= x
        result += (-1)**(len(c)+1) * (numEnd//num - (numStart-1)//num)

print(result)
# Output would look like this:
# >118
```

My question really is how did this person actually figure this out? What type of math is this and why does this work?

If you can at least lead me in the right direction I would be very thankful!

Comment: There's no magic formula or algorithm that leads you to the best solution for a mathematical problem. You develop intuition for them by trying, or thinking through cues that can help, but other than that, i dont really know what you expect as an answer to this question.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Well, I might be asking for a lot here but I'm hoping for a step-by-step thought process on this I guess. But I'd be very interested to know how to get better with these kinds of formulas and maybe where I could learn about this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief summary of parts of the code.

There are two main ideas in the given code. The first idea is that given a positive integer `num` (not necessarily prime), the count of numbers in the range from `numStart` to `numEnd` divisible by `num` is

```
numEnd//num - (numStart-1)//num
```

This because the numbers divisible by `num` from `1` to `numStart` is `(numStart-1)//num` and from `1` to `numEnd` is `numEnd//num`. (I'll let you figure out how the ending values of those ranges are handled correctly by these formulas.)

Here is the second idea. That formula works for each prime number in your given list. But the problem asks for the count of numbers in the range that are divisible by "by *at least one* prime" in that list. If we just add the counts for each prime we will count the number divisible by multiple primes multiple times. The standard way to handle those multiple counts is the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). You should read that article if you are interested in this kind of problem. The code lines

```
for j in range(1,numOfPrimes+1):
    for c in combinations(primes, j):
```

make `c` to be the non-empty subsets of the list of prime numbers. The formula I gave you above is used to find the count for each product of the primes in the subset, and the factor `(-1)**(len(c)+1)` is multiplied to do the proper inclusion/exclusion. All those products are then added. If you did not understand this last part, read the inclusion-exclusion article. I should add that basic number theory tells us that a the members set of distinct primes all divide a number if and only if the product of the prime numbers divides that number--this is why the "prime" restriction is in the problem.

As to how the person figured this out, computer science has shown that there is no guaranteed method to figure out algorithms for problems. Problem solvers just use their knowledge, experience, creativity, and grit to keep on until the problem is solved. The book *How to Solve It* by George Polya is a classic on how to solve problems. I highly recommend the book to you--it is in paperback and pretty cheap.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! Thanks for the book recommendation too.